# how to check if domain group has any kind of permissions to web after ensure

Tags: 2013, development

I am adding user to web, he might be added or might not be.

I want to only give him permissions if he already doesnot have/has.

How can i check.

```
        SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl);
        SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            if (web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
            {
                SPUser newUser = web.EnsureUser("Managers A Portal B");

                here i want to see if user has any permission at all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SPWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms441848(v=office.15).aspx):

```
if(!web.DoesUserHavePermissions(newUser.Login, SPBasePermissions.AddListItems))
{
    // User does not have permissions, so add
}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx) are all the items in the `SPBasePermissions` enumeration.

Comment: Does i use this with domain groups okay ?

Comment: Yes, I believe you can.